# Composition of $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$-$\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ and $\mathcal E$-$\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$-measurable functions.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I've proven $$h(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1/x & : x \neq 0\\
0 & : x = 0
\end{array}
\right.$$

is $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$-$\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$-measurable.

I'm then asked to prove that if $(X, \mathcal E)$ is a measurable space and $f,g$ are $\mathcal E$-$\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$-measurable functions, $g(x) \neq 0$ $\forall \ x \in X$, then $f/g$ is $\mathcal E$-$\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$-measurable.

A hint is given I should use $h$.

I have a theorem saying that if $h$ is $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$-$\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$-measurable and $g$ is $\mathcal E$-$\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$-measurable then $h(g(x)$ is $\mathcal E$-$\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$-measurable.

But how can this be true ? If I set $g(x) =0$ then $g$ is $\mathcal E$-$\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$-measurable, but $h(g(x))$ is not defined ??

Comment: If $g(x)=0$, then $h(g(x))=0$ per definition of $h$. Anyway, you're assuming $g(x)\neq 0$ for all $x$ in your exercise.

Comment: Here's a hint: First prove that the product of two measurable functions is measurable and then use this and your theorem to write $f/g = f \cdot h(g)$.